# How do I overload the assignment operator as to allow my class to equal a primitive type such as 'int'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading, assignment-operator

So I am trying to do a program that is simply overloading many operators, but for some reason whenever I try to overload the assignment operator, I get an error that says

> error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Foo' requested

```
    class Foo {
        int value;
    public:
        operator int() const;
        Foo& operator=(const int &val) { value = val; return this; }
        ...
    };
    int main()
    {
        Foo a = 8, b = 9;
        ...
        return 0;
    }
```

I have also tried it without the operator= statement and without the operator int() const; statement, but I just can't seem to get it to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused assignment with initialization.

```
Foo f = 1; //initialization
f = 2; //assignment
```

You need to make a constructor that accepts an `int` too.

```
Foo(int i) : value(i) {}

//main

Foo f = 1; //uses constructor
```

Being that it is a single argument constructor (converting constructor), if you don't wish `int` to be implicitly convertible to `Foo`, you should make the constructor `explicit`.

Comment: @Zak Do you mean you can't change the `main` function, or the whole source file? If you can't change the file at all, then you can't do anything. Otherwise, just do what I said in my answer and make a constructor.